# Getting window height via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a problem using `$(window).height()`. When I first load the page, it shows 0, I can only get the right number after refreshing it.

I tried to put it in `$(document).ready(function(){})`, in the beginning of JavaScript, in the `$('[data-role="page"]').live('pageshow', function () {})` (it's a jquery mobile site), but nothing works.

How can I get the window height on loading the file without refreshing it?

Comment: It is possible to write some HTML-Code that has content with a height but it's container (e.g. the body or window) has a height of 0. Give me some more code, some HTML and/or CSS.

Comment: Try to alert it on some button click as shown here   http://api.jquery.com/height/  if it is working correctly then there might be some other problem. wait for expert to come up with solid answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$(window).load(function(){ 
    console.log( $(this).height() )
});
```

but the window height is basically always the same. you might want the document body height :

```
$(window).load(function(){ 
    console.log( $(document).height() )
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you passed an empty function to `ready()`, which is why it doesn't do anything.

You can use this shortcut for `$(document).ready(handler)`:

```
$(function() {
  console.log($(window).height());
});
```

Comment: hmmm quite possible.  but then how refreshing is working then ? i am little bit confuse here

Comment: @SaurabhBayani That depends on what he means by refreshing, which is why I asked what exactly he meant with that.

Comment: K. but in this scenario i guess he means "refreshing page". any ways! let him be clear first :)

Comment: sorry, I meant F5 refresh the page - is that anything else I can refresh? :P

Comment: and it's a 'she' by the way, thank you all for your effort ;)

Comment: @the_summer_bee Your picture is too small to tell. I usually go by [**this idea**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender-neutral_pronoun#Universal_.22he.22). -- As for anything else to refresh: Sometimes people say they "refresh a value" so you might have called the function twice for example.

Comment: @the_summer_bee,   oh sorry ! Seriously your picture thumbnail is small to tell. any ways happy coding  :)   .

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an error somewhere in your code.

```
$(window).height();
```

should return you real height.

```
$('#index').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){    
    alert($(window).height());
});
```

Here's an working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/JmqX6/

Now mobile phones are something completely different, for this to correctly work on mobile phones you also need a vireport tag inside your HEAD:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=device-width" />
```